# Simple XOR encryption giving unexpected results

Tags: c, windows, encryption, xor

```
...
char text[256];
fgets(text, 255, stdin);
xorEncrypt(text, 'a');
...

void xorEncrypt(char *string, char key)
    {

    int i, string_length = strlen(string);

    for(i=0; i<string_length; i++)
    {
        string[i]=string[i] ^ key;
    }
    printf("%s", string);
}

//user enters "test"
//result is: §♦↕§k (correct)
//user enters "abcdefg"
//result is empty
//user enters "testbca"
//result is "§♦↕§♥☻" (incorrect) and there is a beep sound
```

When I use some chars like 'a', 'b', 'c' as a key, it gives either an empty result or some random signs, but using other letters like 'A', 'I'..., works normally and I can decrypt it.

Comment: can you show please full-self-contained example input and result output  expected/actual?

Comment: Your code looks fine, unless you pass a _string-literal_ or any other constant string. Please provide a [mcve] and tell exactly what you input and expected output.

Comment: Added more info and examples.

Comment: In `xorEncrypt(text, "a");`  you must pas "a" as a char, not as a string, so as `'a'`. Didn't your compiler warn you?

Comment: I used 'a', just wrote it wrong here. Edited.

Comment: 1) C strings are terminated by a `0`-character. 2) what is `'a' ^ 'a'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code seems fine. Probably you want to print the resulting string, but the XOR may have turned parts of it into non-printable characters. Note also that there may now be null characters in the string (e.g. 'a ^ 'a' = 0) so the end is not determined anymore by a terminating null character.

Comment: The string must not contain the same character that is used as a key?

Comment: No reason why it should not. But to know the length of the string you cannot rely on the terminating null character; you have to keep track of its length in a separate variable.